# Typeahead only works with local datums

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-typeahead

I use typeahead in my web app, but it only works with local data. Any suggestion on this problem?
With local data:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/w1kdydubfx35662/2.png

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#location').typeahead({
         name: 'locations',
             local: ["suggestion1", "suggestion2", "suggestion3", "suggestion4","abc"],
             limit:4 
         });
     });
</script>
```

With prefetch data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/au7rabcfd7qmfuy/1.png

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#location').typeahead({
     name: 'locations',
         prefetch: {url:"http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/countries.json",
                    ttl:100
                   },
         limit:4 
     });
 });
 </script>
```

The input field is:

```
<div class="input-group" >
<div class="form-inline">
  <%= form_tag(location_search_path,method: "get" ) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag('location', params[:location], :size => 150, :placeholder=> "Enter city or zip code", :autofocus=>true) %> 
  <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn  btn-success ", id:"bu") do %>
   Search 
         <i class="icon-search"></i>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: oh my let me clean this up a little bit.

Comment: I'm soory for the mess..Do you have any idea on it?

Comment: i recently implemented a very similar autocomplete function for one of my own apps. When I get back from work I will take a look to see if any of that code would be of use.

Comment: Alright so I have taken a look at my code and here is what I can tell you. I had no luck doing any external loading of the list. The only way that I was accomplishing this was much like your original method of storing locally. I assume you may be able to load the list in a before action.

Comment: i tried my best to show you what I did for my solution but I am not sure how helpful that will actually be for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript to setup autocomplete**

```
    $(function() {

        spells = ["Barrier", "Clairvoyance", "Clarity", "Cleanse", "Exhaust", "Flash", "Garrison", "Ghost", "Heal", "Ignite", "Revive", "Smite", "Teleport"]

        $(".summoner_spells").autocomplete({
                 source: spells,
                 minLength: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Form for the autocomplete field:**

```
<%= simple_form_for @game do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :summoner1, input_html: {class: "summoner_spells"} %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

My solution is obviously not loading not locally but this is my preferred method as I have a very small list that I like to have control over.